# Parameter Data Type to Accept Both GDB or Feature Dataset

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

I would like the parameters in my script to accept both gdb workspaces or feature datasets. I have tried both "DEWorkspace" and "DEFeatureDataset", but both of these accept either gdb or feature datasets, and not both.

Here's a list of all options: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm

Any idea on how to work around this? I'm thinking there might be a filter for "DEWorkspace", but haven't managed to figure out how that works.

Answer (score 2):

In a Python toolbox, you can set a list of datatypes for a parameter:

```
def getParameterInfo(self):
  par0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName = 'Parameter 1',
    name = 'par0',
    datatype = ['DEWorkspace', 'DEFeatureDataset'],
    parameterType = 'required',
    direction = 'input')
```

Comment: That actually results in a free-for-all data type that accepts any input, and not just a workspace or feature dataset. I no longer need this functionality in my script, but thank you for your feedback.

Comment: No problem. I have used this exact list to filter input types and it works great. Mind sharing your code?